# ArabLuaTeX brackets in UTF-8 encoding

Tags: unicode, brackets, arabic, arabluatex

I am having issues with square brackets, parentheses, etc. in Arabic environment with unicode input. I appreciate any help: Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont{Amiri}[Script=Arabic]
\begin{document}
\begin{txarab}
        هَيَّا (نَنْزِلْ) إِلَيْهِمْ وَنُبَلْبِلْ \abraces{لِسَانَهُمْ}، حَتَّى لَا <يَفْهَمَ> [بَعْضُهُمْ] كَلامَ بَعْضٍ.%
\end{txarab}

\begin{arab}[fullvoc]
    hayyA (nanzil) 'ilayhim wa nubalbil \abraces{lisAnahum}, .hattY lA <yafhama> [b`.duhum] kalAm ba`.diN. 
\end{arab}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `txarab` environment does not call the functions that process braces and parentheses, contrary to `arab`.  So this will work:

```latex
\begin{arab}
        هَيَّا (نَنْزِلْ) إِلَيْهِمْ وَنُبَلْبِلْ \abraces{لِسَانَهُمْ}، حَتَّى لَا <يَفْهَمَ> [بَعْضُهُمْ] كَلامَ بَعْضٍ.%
\end{arab}
```

That said, it is advisable not to use `arab` with Unicode Arabic, except in cases like this one, of course.

Comment: Thank you so much! Important exception to note.

Comment: You are welcome.  As a general principle, `arab` should only be used with unicode input when such functions as this one are needed.